# FORE! Choosing a data type for my horrendous golf game

Tags: python

Ive started learning Python and decided to give myself a golf related project to work on.  My question revolves around choosing the best data type to use.  Now i know th3nanswer to this is based on requirements but tht isnt helping me.

Besides simple data like name, date, name of course, etc., ill alao be generating 9 and 18 hole scores for multiple players in my locl society. 
While keeping a historical record of past scores is nice i may want to perform some analytics across my dataset to find handicaps, hardest holes, etc.  And, yes, i know there are apps out there aldeady  im doing this to learn.  ;)

So....which data structur should i use to work with?  Lists, dictionaries, numpy arrats, objects, or a combination?

Many thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want a database, if you just want to store data. Look into SQLite.

Comment: And perhaps, you should use a combination of the types you mentioned.
Yes, this is a it depends question. We cant model data for you or give suggestions without modelling the data for you as an result. Read about the datatypes and look at example ussage, then you will know what is appropriate or why not test and learn by doing. This isnt something you have to get right from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @ COLDSPEED.  Indeed the goal is to integrate a cloud based database solution once I start tracking users and recalling historical data.  Right now I am focusing on my Pythom.  Its a long road.  ;)

Comment: Cheers @David Bern.  I know you're right on the money.  I have four years of data for a small par three course in London (Duke's Meadows).  I'd like to recalculate the score index for the holes base don this data which includes thousands pf rounds played.

In order to do this I am going to experiment with a dictionary which uses the hole as the key and an numpy array as a value.  Not sure its possible but thats the plan.

But then I'd like to incorporate the date in my hybrid datatype.  And dates, as I have learned, seem to be more complicated than one might first assume.

Comment: @all -i may post back with future updates and or questions unless you can point to a better forum for such a Q&A.  thanks all